# How to redirect sub1.site1.com to sub2.site2.com/subdir using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cname

As i know cname can't do this. So i have this rule in .htaccess file on sub1.site1.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub2.site2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]
```

It's not working...

Comment: My fault, the rule above is working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Point all sub domains (record *, type A) to hosting (code)

In .haccess add lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain.ext [NC] # %1

RewriteRule (.*) domain.ext/%1/$1 [L] # $1
```